# VBA x IE - coletar dados de uma tabela

Tags: html, vba, internet-explorer, excel-vba

Estou programando em VBA uma coleta de informações no site do banco central. Acontece que a página não carrega totalmente e quando a macro termina apenas alguns registros foram carregados na planilha. Acredito que a página tenha alguma evento que vai carregando os registro conforme o usuário vai rolando a página para baixo. Alguém já teve esse problema? Como conseguiu resolver? Segue o código.

```
Sub capDadosTable()

    Dim IE As Object
    Dim e As Object
    Dim el As Object

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With IE
        'página com o formulario a ser preenchido
        .Navigate "https://www3.bcb.gov.br/expectativas/publico/consulta/serieestatisticas"
        .Visible = True

        'aguarda a página carregar por completo
        While .busy Or .ReadyState <> 4
        Application.Wait TimeSerial(Hour(Now), Minute(Now), Second(Now) + 1)
        Wend

        'seleciona o item do combobox 'indicador',pelo Index, neste caso o item 4
        .document.GetElementByID("indicador").selectedindex = 4
        'força rodar o evento do combobox
        .document.all("indicador").FireEvent ("onchange")

        'aguarda a página carregar por completo
        While .busy Or .ReadyState <> 4
        Application.Wait TimeSerial(Hour(Now), Minute(Now), Second(Now) + 1)
        Wend

        'Seleciona o indicador IPCA
        .document.GetElementByID("grupoIndicePreco:opcoes_5").Click

        'seleciona o item do combobox 'calculo' pelo Index, neste caso o 2
        .document.GetElementByID("calculo").selectedindex = 2

        'seleciona a periodicidade anual
        .document.GetElementByID("periodicidade").selectedindex = 2
        'força rodar o evento do combobox
        .document.all("periodicidade").FireEvent ("onchange")

        'aguarda a página carregar por completo
        While .busy Or .ReadyState <> 4
        Application.Wait TimeSerial(Hour(Now), Minute(Now), Second(Now) + 1)
        Wend

        'inclui a data de inicio no combobox tfDataInicial - primeiro dia do ano anterior
        .document.all("tfDataInicial").Value = Format(DateSerial(Year(Now) - 1, 1, 1), "dd/mm/yyyy")

        'inclui a data de hoje no combobox tfDataFinal
        .document.all("tfDataFinal").Value = Format(Now(), "dd/mm/yyyy")

        'testa a lista de anos do combobox AnoInicial, se for igual ao ano corrente, seleciona-o.
        Set e = .document.all("divPeriodoRefereEstatisticas:grupoAnoReferencia:anoReferenciaInicial")

        For Each o In e.Options
        If o.Text = Format(Year(Now), "@") Then
            o.Selected = True
            Exit For
            Set e = Nothing
        End If
        Next

        'testa a lista de anos do combobox AnoFinal, se for igual ao ano corrente, seleciona-o.
        Set e = .document.all("divPeriodoRefereEstatisticas:grupoAnoReferencia:anoReferenciaFinal")

        For Each o In e.Options
        If o.Text = Format(Year(Now), "@") Then
            o.Selected = True
            Exit For
            Set e = Nothing
        End If
        Next


        'clica no botão que gerará a tabela com os resultados
        .document.all("btnConsultar").Click

        'aguarda a página carregar por completo
        While .busy Or .ReadyState <> 4
        Application.Wait TimeSerial(Hour(Now), Minute(Now), Second(Now) + 1)
        Wend

        '**************************************************
            'Carrega os dados da tabela gerada para a Sheets IPCA
            Set sh = Sheets("IPCA")
            Set tabela = IE.document.all.tags("tr")

            linha = 1
            For Each el In tabela

            If el.innertext = "" Then GoTo proximo
            sh.Cells(linha, 1) = el.innertext

            linha = linha + 1

       proximo:
            Next

            End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Oi, Wanderlei!

Em primeiro lugar, meus parabéns pelo código, coisa finíssima!

Por incrível que pareça o problema aqui é da arquitetura da página do BC, que carrega somente as 78 primeiras linhas (no seu exemplo).

Isso é pra economizar processamento, e evitar Full Table Scan.

Eu consegui adicionar controle de Scroll na página, mas precisa fazer o scroll do frame dos indicadores, o que eu acho que não é muito simples de conseguir.

A solução é aumentar o último "time" e quando aparecer a página final, você mesmo fazer o scroll (o que vai forçar o carregamento de todas as linhas), sugeri 20 segundos para isso

Assim quando entrar pro For teremos todas as TAGs TR carregadas.

Tomei a liberdade de mudar para GetElemetsByTagName e colunar data e índice.

```
  .Document.parentWindow.Scroll 0&, 900& 'SCROLL INICIAL
  .Visible = True 
  'ASSIM QUE DER ESSE VISIBLE CORRE, VOCÊ TEM 20 SEGUNDOS PRA DAR SCROLL NO FRAME
   Application.Wait TimeSerial(Hour(Now), Minute(Now), Second(Now) + 20)
        
        '**************************************************
            'Carrega os dados da tabela gerada para a Sheets IPCA
            Set sh = Sheets("IPCA")
            Set tabela = IE.Document.GetElementsByTagName("tr")
            linha1 = 1
            linha2 = 4
            
            sh.Cells(linha2 - 1, 2).Value = "Valor"

            
            For xt = 0 To tabela.Length - 1
                If Len(tabela.Item(xt).innertext) < 2 Then
                'nada a fazer
                
                ElseIf InStr(1, tabela.Item(xt).innertext, "Sistema") > 0 _
                Or InStr(1, tabela.Item(xt).innertext, ",") = 0 Then
                'cabeçalho
                    sh.Cells(linha1, 1).Value = tabela.Item(xt).innertext
                    linha1 = linha1 + 1
                ElseIf InStr(1, tabela.Item(xt).innertext, ",") > 0 Then
                'valor
                    sh.Cells(linha2, 2).Value = tabela.Item(xt).innertext
                    linha2 = linha2 + 1
                End If
            Next
            

            End With
```